# checkBox in gridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

i am using checkbox in gridview..to get the checkbox id i am using the following code..

```
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox chkDelete = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows.Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect");
        if (chkDelete != null)
        {
            if (chkDelete.Checked)
            {
                strID = GridView1.Rows.Cells[1].Text;
                idCollection.Add(strID);
            }
        }
    }
```

BUT THE KEYWORD "CELLS"..do not support..i am getting an error.."System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cells' "

Comment: I don't know why you are looping the statement as you are hard coding the values for the cells like cells[0] and cells[1] what if you need other rows data

Answer (score 3):

This is the way you have to check

```
foreach (GridViewRow grRow in grdACH.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkItem = (CheckBox)grRow.FindControl("checkRec");
        if (chkItem.Checked)
        {
            strID = ((Label)grRow.FindControl("lblBankType")).Text.ToString();
         }
}
```

Comment: if (chkItem.Checked)
        {
            
         }how to decide using above code which checkbox is checked

Comment: You will get the control corresponding to that and if it is checked it will definitely show you as checked have you tried that or else post the design of your aspx page so that i will give as per your requirement

Comment: Name of the `gridivew` in his case it is default `GridView1`

Answer (score 2):

That's correct; the [`GridViewRowCollection` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrowcollection.aspx) does not contain either a method or a property with the name `Cells`. The reason that matters is that the `Rows` property of the `GridView` control returns a `GridViewRowCollection` object, and when you call `GridView1.Rows.Cells`, it is searching for a `Cells` property on the `GridViewRowCollection` object returned by the `Row` property.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    CheckBox chkDelete = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("chkSelect");
    if (chkDelete != null)
    {

        if (chkDelete.Checked)
        {
            strID = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
            idCollection.Add(strID);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach (GridViewRow rowitem in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chkDelete = (CheckBox)rowitem.Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect");
                if (chkDelete != null)
                {
                    if (chkDelete.Checked)
                    {
                        strID = rowitem.Cells[1].Text;
                        idCollection.Add(strID);
                    }
                }


            }
```