# Getting Checkbox from Databound Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

Is there a way to retrieve whether a Checkbox field is checked in a databound gridview in ASP.NET? I can retrieve all other cell values in a `foreach` loop with `cell.Text`. Since it is databound (to an ObjectDataSource) the columns and cells don't have explicitly set IDs and I can't seem to find a property that would let me know the cell contains a checkbox or just text. All cells are of type DataControlFieldCell so I can't check based on type either. Thoughts?

EDIT:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in report_gv.Rows)
{
   data += "<TR>";
   foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
   {
      data += "<TD>" + cell.Text + "</TD>";
      //If this is a checkbox (bit value from the DB) cell.Text isn't going to return anything
   }
   data += "</TR>";
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your partial code? It seems that you cannot use FindControl since you do not set IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in myGridView) {
  foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells) {
    foreach (Control ctrl in cell.Controls) {
      if (ctrl is CheckBox) {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)ctrl;
        // use cb
      } else if (cell is TextBox) {
      } else if (cell is Label) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can expand this to process however you need.

Comment: This actually works which is interesting because when I was checking cell.Controls[0] I was getting an Exception. Anyhow...thanks for all your help! I was beginning to think it wasn't possible.

Comment: It works because not all cells have controls. When you checked Controls[0] in a cell without any controls, you would get an exception. Using `foreach` covers this condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. But easier is to convert to a `<TemplateField>`, which will allow you to assign an ID to your `CheckBox`. Then your foreach goes:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in myGridView) {
  CheckBox myCB = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("gvIdentifier");

  // Do something with myCB
}
```

Comment: I tried this and am stepping through the code behind and when my foreach loop lands on the cell with the checkbox it still says the ClientID is report_gv_ctl03_ctl02.

Comment: You can just use theRow.FindControl("myCheckBox") to identify the item. I have added this to my answer.

Comment: But I want ALL the values from ALL the cells...in order. Not just the Checkbox value. There is a reason I'm parsing through the cells and not just using FindControl.

Comment: I have done this before, but you will have to write code to cast the containers inside each table cell. I would recommend placing breakpoints inside your loop, and using the immediates window in the debugger to investigate the data types and drill down into the cell contents. I have added another answer to show how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

In  [GridView.RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Event you can access each and every `checkbox` that inside each row. 
Try something like this

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chb1" runat="server">
</ItemTemplate>

protected void GvRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
            var chb = (CheckBox) e.Row.FindControl("chb1");
            var ischeck = false;
            if(chb != null)
            {
                if(chb.Checked)
                {
                    ischeck = true;
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: I believe the original question wants to know if the items are checked, OnRowDataBound won't help there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `FindControl` on the `GridViewItem` and search by the checkbox ID as you have it in the `ItemTemplate` definition.

there are plenty of examples on FindControl GridView out there

for example check this out: [checkBox in gridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684881/checkbox-in-gridview/5684942#5684942)

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I'm not really trying to FindControl() checkboxes explicitly. I'm trying to loop through all cells and handle the checkbox values appropriately.

Comment: FindControl will work if the CheckBox is a server control with an ID and will work always, manual parse or assumptions on the location of the control in the html tree would work once, eventually, then could fail in the future if you add columns or change the nesting of controls. The suggested approach is FindControl.